# Powershell : Extract an address from a web page

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to extract an address from a web page.

I want to extract the string "url/yyyy-MM-dd/YXZ" from this page.

it will always start with "url/" then "date/" and "XYZ" will be a changing number.

I download the page from the server

```
$url = "https://server.local/"
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.Webclient
$rawHTML = $webClient.DownloadString($url)
```

Then the string will begin with "url/" and date

`$Address = "url/" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd/")`

example of rawHTML string to extract

```
<div class="block-content">
<a href="/url/2020-09-11/123" class="dm_emission_card_wrapper">
<span class="dm_emission_card_img">
```

I don't know what to do next.

I have tried index of + variable, but it displays -1

`$rawHTML.IndexOf($Address)`

I guess I can't put a variable with / inside
Then i can use trim cut the string

How can i get this ? thank you.

Comment: Don't put `'` around variables! `$rawHTML.IndexOf($Adress)`

Comment: Please show the relevant example of rawHTML that you're trying to match?

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if helps or any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
$url = "http://192.168.0.11:8080/"
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.Webclient
$rawHTML = $webClient.DownloadString($url)
$regex = 'url\/' + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd/") + '(.){3}'
$rawHTML -match $regex
$matches[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have several entries with different dates, i need to only select the date of the day.

Comment: @Dirty Just modify the regex as seen in updated answer